# How to search and replace while ignoring placeholders?

Tags: regex, replace

I'd like to perform a search and replace, preferably in VSCode, but a command line program or something like a Python script will do.
Ideally, I would be able to perform the search and replace across multiple files in a directory tree.
I ran into an issue where I wanted to replace `twoword` with `two word` except where it appeared as `--twoword`.
I couldn't do it with regex.
Another example would be to replace `{something}` with `[something]`, where `something` is any and all text surrounded by curly braces.
That is, if I have `{something}` and `{something else}`, I don't want to do a find and replace for each possible combination.

I imagine it would be something like

find: `{$1}`

replace: `[$1]`

This looks like something I can find quickly if I know what it's called, but I don't know what this process is called, so I'm not sure what to search for online.
It's possible to do this sort of thing in a single file with a Vim macro, but I'm looking for something that works for multiple files.

Comment: You need to capture what's in between and then yes, use a backreference. `\(([^()]*)\)` -> `[$1]` to replace round brackets with square ones, etc.

Comment: Will this also work for replacing text that is not surrounded by brackets like the `--twoword` example I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, `--(\S+)` > `[$1]`